# Como validar un input time en .net MVC

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy validando mi campo "Hora" con expresiones regulares, pero al momento de enviar los datos, NO VALIDA EL CAMPO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya incluí las expresiones regulares y la librería JqueryVal

**Clase**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

//Directivas
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace wsCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsCharla
    {
        public string ID_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Título de la charla:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el título de la charla")]
        public string titulo_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descripción de la charla:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese la descripción de la charla")]
        public string descrip_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha de la charla:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una fecha válida")]
        public string fecha_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hora de la charla:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d{2}:\d{2}", ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una hora válida")]
        public string hora_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dirección de la charla:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese la dirección de la charla")]
        public string lugar_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sede de la charla:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione una sede para la charla")]
        public string sede_Charla { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Requisitos para la charla:")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese los requisitos para la charla")]
        public string requisito_Charla { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Vista**

```
    @model wsCharlas.Models.ClsCharla

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear Charla";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Crear Charla:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>Aquí usted podrá colocar todos los datos respectivos de la charla que desee crear.</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <!--    <div class="form-horizontal"> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.hora_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hora_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hora_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sede_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sede_Charla, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sedes, "Seleccione una Sede", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sede_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</div> -->
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta era que faltaba colocar la anotación [Required] en mi atributo "Hora".